# Spring MVC @Validation with Marker Interface in Generic Controller Method

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, bean-validation, marker-interfaces

I have a Spring MVC survey application where the Controller method called by each form POST is virtually identical:

```
@PostMapping("/1")
public String processGroupOne (
        Model model,
        @ModelAttribute("pageNum") int pageNum, 
        @ModelAttribute(GlobalControllerAdvice.SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME) @Validated(SurveyGroupOne.class) SurveyCommand surveyCommand, 
        BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        LOG.debug(result.getAllErrors().toString());
        model.addAttribute("pageNum", pageNum);
        return "survey/page".concat(Integer.toString(pageNum));
    }
    pageNum++;
    model.addAttribute("pageNum", pageNum);
    return "redirect:/survey/".concat(Integer.toString(pageNum));
}
```

The only difference is what part of the SurveyCommand object is validated at each stop along the way. This is designated by the marker interface passed to the @Validated() annotation. The marker interfaces (SurveyGroupOne, SurveyGroupTwo, etc) are just that, markers:

```
public interface SurveyGroupOne {}
public interface SurveyGroupTwo {}
...
```

and they are applied to properties of objects in the SurveyCommand object:

```
public class Person {
    @NotBlank(groups = {
                    SurveyGroupTwo.class, 
                    SurveyGroupThree.class})
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank(groups = {
                    SurveyGroupTwo.class, 
                    SurveyGroupThree.class})
    private String lastName;
...
}
```

*My question:* how can I make the method generic and still use the marker interface specific to the page being processed? Something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/{pageNum}")
public String processGroupOne (
        Model model,
        @PathVariable("pageNum") int pageNum, 
        @ModelAttribute(GlobalControllerAdvice.SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME) 
            @Validated(__what goes here??__) SurveyCommand surveyCommand, 
        BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        LOG.debug(result.getAllErrors().toString());
        model.addAttribute("pageNum", pageNum);
        return "survey/page".concat(Integer.toString(pageNum));
    }
    pageNum++;
    model.addAttribute("pageNum", pageNum);
    return "redirect:/survey/".concat(Integer.toString(pageNum));
}
```

How can I pass the proper marker interface to @Validated based solely on the pageNum @PathVariable (or any other parameter)?

Answer (score 0):

Because `@Validated` is an annotation, it requires its arguments to be available during compilation and hence static. You can still use it but in this case you will have N methods, where N is a number of steps. To distinguish one step from another you can [use `params` argument of `@PostMapping` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-params-and-headers).

There is also another way where you need to inject `Validator` to the controller and [invoke it directly with an appropriate group](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-groups) that you need.